# Error Query: DELETE and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM programSchedule 
LEFT JOIN program ON programSchedule.pid = program.id 
WHERE program.channel_id = 10
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LEFT JOIN program ON
>   programSchedule.pid = program.id' at
>   line 1

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify what table to delete from.

```
DELETE programSchedule.*
FROM programSchedule LEFT JOIN program ON programSchedule.pid = program.id
WHERE program.channel_id = 10
```

Note: Change the join to a `INNER JOIN` since you are filtering by `program.channel_id`

```
DELETE programSchedule.*
FROM programSchedule INNER JOIN program ON programSchedule.pid = program.id
WHERE program.channel_id = 10
```

Comment: Note: If you want to delete from **both** tables, you can do this by first creating a temp table. Please post your table definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Because two tables are involved, you need to say which table you'd like to delete from. So in order to delete the rows in the `programSchedule` table, you can do this:

```
DELETE programSchedule.* 
FROM programSchedule 
LEFT JOIN program ON programSchedule.pid = program.id 
WHERE program.channel_id = 10
```